# I am trying to install dependencies but it tries to remove games and programs

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install dependencies but it says packages were added automatically installed and are no longer required but the packages are games and programs
this is what the terminal says
`The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  assaultcube-data cmake-data gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
  libcec4 libcrossguid0 libfstrcmp0 libjsoncpp1 libllvm3.9 libmicrohttpd12
  libp8-platform2 libpcrecpp0v5 librhash0 libshairplay0 libtfm1 libuv1
  libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 python-bluez python-cryptodome python-wxgtk3.0
  python-wxversion python3-distro python3-evdev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.Suggested packages:
  gvfs:i386
Recommended packages:
  libgail-common:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  assaultcube clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam cmake curl kodi kodi-x11
  libclamav9 libcurl4 lutris playonlinux steam-launcher`

Comment: Looks like normal behavior to me. If you remove `assaultcube`, it seems quite normal that `assaultcube-data` will become eligible for autoremoval.

Comment: but i did not remove assaultcube. In fact i just recently installed it

Comment: Your output: `The following packages will be REMOVED: ...assaultcube...` Perhaps you didn't INTEND to remove assaultcube. Perhaps you tried to install something that conflicted with assaultcube. You didn't show us your input command, so we don't know.